# Buttons is not working properly BOT Framework when text is long

Tags: bots, botframework, chatbot, azure-bot-service, webbot

I am creating the buttons dynamically in the BOT framework. The issue I am facing is that if the text of the button is coming long it's not coming as a button but as a list of text and I am not even able to click them because on the click of each button my different activity will start.

Thanks

Comment: I don't think if button text long will create problems in bot, better to provide some screenshots and the code.

Comment: If you share some code, we will be able to help. In some cases, the length of a sugggested action (if that is what you mean with button) text should be below a certain number ( I think is is 20 characters), otherwise the suggested action will become a list-item. Depends how you create the button.

Comment: @Hessel yes it's created as a List Item. I do not have a problem with List Item but is there any way to click them after that?

Comment: I don't think so.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you [Hessel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7095607/hessel) and [Bipin Bhandari](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1350632/bipin-bhandari). Posting your discussions as answer to help other community members.

> Text of the suggested action (Button) should be less than certain
> number (~ 20 Characters). If not, the suggested action become a
> list-item. There is no option to perform the **CLICK** operation on
> the list-items.